# Google Collab : Read gsheet file from Google drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to read a gsheet file in Google drive using Google Collab. I tried using drive.mount to get the file but I don't know how to get a dataframe with pandas from there. Here what I tried to do :

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import os
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive

# setup
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
drive.mount('/content/drive',force_remount=True)

# read data and put it in a dataframe
gsheets = gc.open_by_url('/content/drive/MyDrive/test/myGoogleSheet.gsheet')
```

As you can tell, I am quite lost with the libraries. I want to use the ability to access the drive with the drive library, to get the content from gspread, and read with pandas.

Can anyone help me find a solution, please ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for my problem by looking further into the library [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html). I was able to load the gsheet file by id or by url which I did not know. Then I manage to get the content of a sheet and read it as pandas dataframe. Here is the code :

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread
import pandas as pd
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# setup
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

# read data and put it in a dataframe
# spreadsheet = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/google_sheet_id/edit#gid=0')
spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key('google_sheet_id')

wks = spreadsheet.worksheet('sheet_name')

data = wks.get_all_values()
headers = data.pop(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)

print(df)
```